# Function from external JS file not being called

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, webpack

I am using webpack and firebase.

I have this line in my package.json > `"start": "webpack-dev-server ./index.js",`

In my index.js file I have function

```
logUserIn(){
  //does stuff
};
```

In my index.html file I have this line > `<input type="submit" onclick=logUserIn() value="Log in">`

When I click that button I get this error > `Uncaught ReferenceError: logUserIn is not defined`

I also have this line in my index.html file > `<script src="bundle.js"></script>` that should link to the bundle file that contains index.js correct?

Finally, I have done a console.log in the index.js saying `console.log('hello')`, when I refresh the page, the hello appears thus meaning that the index.html is calling index.js through bundle.js so why on earth will it not recognize my method name?

It is definitely not a typo either as i have copied and pasted

Comment: `window.logUserIn = logUserIn;`

Comment: well either the function is not in global scope or the function is not defined, or you misspelled something. ANd hopefully it is just a typo you missed the `function` before `logUserIn`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use Webpack, you are assumed to be using [modules](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html). If your code isn't organized this way, it can create some issues.

Specifically to your problem, your function `logUserIn()` is there, but it's inside a module, meaning that it's a private function. It's not seen in the global scope, so your `index.html` can't "see" the function to call it.

In order to make it globally available, you'll need to export the function.

However, unless you have a specific reason to have the `logUserIn()` in the HTML, I would recommend switching up your code. Typically you want to keep your markup and your logic separate, so in this case your code would look more like:

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById('loginButton').onclick = logUserIn
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="submit" id="loginButton" value="Log in">
```

Also, if the button in question is a form, you'll need to overwrite the default functionality of a form with `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: @epascarello Care to elaborate what the issue is? I'd love to clean up my answer to better solve the problem.

Comment: You are executing the function.

Comment: Updated the answer. Thanks, @epascarello !

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest importing your JS file directly into your HTML pages, then check if the problem is solve. if not, Check on the console, under sources, to check if your file is correctly loaded.
If you file is loaded but still doesn't work, check the order you placed your JS files, maybe move it to the top.
Hopes it helps ! 

 - Nic